# How to extract letters from a string using Firebird SQL

Tags: firebird

I want to implement a stored procedure that extract letters from a varchar in firebird.

Example :

```
v_accountno' is of type varchar(50) and has the following values 
accountno 1 - 000023208821 
accountno 2 - 390026826850868140H
accountno 3 - 0700765001003267KAH
```

I want to extract the letters from v_accountno and output it in `o_letter`. 
In my example:  `o_letter` will store `H` for accountno 2 and `KAH` for accountno 3.

I tried the following stored procedure, which obviously won't work for accountno 3. (Please help).

```sql
  CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SP_EXTRACT_LETTER
  returns (
      o_letter varchar(50))
  as
  declare variable v_accountno varchar(50);
  begin
       v_accountno = '390026826850868140H';

       if (not (:v_accountno similar to '[[:DIGIT:]]*')) then
       begin
           -- My SP won't work in for accountno 3 '0700765001003267KAH'
           v_accountno = longsubstr(v_accountno, strlen(v_accountno), strlen(v_accountno));
           o_letter = v_accountno;
       end

      suspend;
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to replace every digits with empty string like:

```
o_letter  = REPLACE(v_accountno, '0', '')
o_letter  = REPLACE(o_letter, '1', '')
o_letter  = REPLACE(o_letter, '2', '')
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Firebird 3, you can use [`substring`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-substring) for this, using its regex facility (using the `similar` clause):

```sql
substring(v_accountno similar '[[:digit:]]*#"[[:alpha:]]*#"' escape '#')
```

See also [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=aab8db22535c9ba96528b1fdaa787aaf).